# validation against a SQL table

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I've always done validation by pulling the entirety of a SQL table into an array, and searching it for the value I was validating.  (Is Joe Smith already in my list of users?)

Is it more effective to do a more specific SQL query looking for that value, and returning true or false?

If so, I would like to see a code example, please.

I've been attempting to do this, but keep running into "Unknown column 'variablename' in 'where clause'"

(edit:)
For example sake, here is some code.  I'm attempting to query a SQL table for a specific variable (a user).  I then just need to know if it did or did not find the user in the table.

```
//$value = "Joe Smith"

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usernames WHERE fullname= $value",$db);

$rowcheck = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($rowcheck > '0') {
// The value was found in the table.
}
```

Comment: If you would post a bit of your code (e.g. the query you're running against the database with the lines around it), it's helpful to better understand your issue and to leave more useful answers. Help us to help you.

Comment: to expand a little: yes, it would be more efficient.  it sounds like you have the right general idea, but to fix the sql bug we need to see what you are using (also, you don't really need to read a boolean - it's often simpler to just select something if there's a match and then use the database api to see whether any data were selected at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulling the entire table is a bad idea. If you happen to have a few million rows in your database, good luck validating this in code. Always narrow down the data transfered with a WHERE clause. If you have the correct indexes, the statement will be fast and your frontend code will be simpler.

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE name='Joe Smith'
```

Check if this returns any rows. Concerning your error, I guess you used the wrong quotes (single quotes).

Edit: You need quotes around string literals

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usernames WHERE fullname='$value'",$db);
```

Comment: Wow, its always something so simple!  Thanks